# MQ Statistics Queue - how is this affected by PCF Requests?

Tags: monitoring, ibm-mq

Lo all,

I was wondering, if I was to set STATQ to ON on my Queue Manager and began to track the statistics of a queue manager and it's associated queues...

Then if I was to do a PCF CMQC.MQIA_MSG_DEQ_COUNT request, would this affect the information I was getting through the statistics queue?

I'd think "yes", but I thought I'd ask here before I actually put it in place myself and tried it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

Yes, it does affect. Because to inquire the statistics, a inquire message is put to `SYSTEM.ADMIN.COMMAND.QUEUE`. You can test this with keeping MQ Explorer open and running amqsmon in a command window. You will notice both Put and Get count increasing.

Comment: That's ok, that's as I intend it to be - and isn't really an answer to the question :)